# Что необходимо знать?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, работа

Когда в описании вакансии пишется:

> Базовые знания языка C# и платформы .NET Framework

то какими конкретными знаниями и навыками требуется обладать?

Comment: Ну вот, как `GC` устроен, вы, например, знаете?

Answer (score 2):

Раз: [C# Language Specification 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029).

Два: [.NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2(v=vs.100).aspx).

Три: [.NET Framework Guidelines and Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184412.aspx).

Английский язык еще надо знать. Это чисто специализированная информация, в идеале еще надо понимать базовые принципы построения этого языка вроде автоматической сборки мусора или того что там нет глобальных переменных, множественного наследования, есть перегрузка операторов, практически отсутствуют неявные преобразовния типов и.т.д.

Вообще этот вопрос надо задать на собеседовании, а не на форуме программистов. Он слишком расплывчатый и на него можно ответить как угодно.

Еще довольно забавный известный документ. [Матрица компетентности](http://www.indiangeek.net/wp-content/uploads/Programmer%20competency%20matrix.htm) программиста. Junior это 2^N (левая колонка). Конечно весьма условно и спорно, но зато применимо ко всем разработчикам, а не только .NET

Comment: Я, честно говоря, думаю, что даже `Jon Skeet` досконально не знает всей спецификации `C#,` поэтому это - пустая трата времени.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Да конечно читать эти 500 страниц с экрана(да и любые другие спецификации) это идиотское занятие, но по крайней мере там вполне можно найти ответ на вопрос по теме. Да и вообще ответ на этот вопрос надо спросить на собеседовании а не на форуме программистов. Он слишком расплывчатый.

Comment: @igumnov В спецификации можно найти ответ на свой вопрос, когда знаешь **что искать.** А у людей, которые знают, что искать, обычно не возникают вопросы типа "Что нужно знать для вакансии `Junior C# Developer'a`?" :)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Бегло просмотрев ее содержание очень быстро понимаешь что вообще можно найти. А это может быть весьма полезно для новичка. Хотя конечно практику не заменишь чтением содержания спецификации.

Answer (score 2):

Получите сертификат начального уровня. Типа как-то Microsoft Cerified Application Developer или Microsoft Technology Associates - это будет как раз базовый уровень.

Погуглите и пройдите в онлайне пару-тройку проверочных тестиков и все поймете что надо знать.